# Iterate slices of size N over some contiguous container

Tags: rust, data-conversion, iterable

let assume that we have a vector of points written as a flat sequence of integers. size of vector is precise and we want to convert it to vector of `Point` structs. So my conversion currently looks like this.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}
impl Point {
    fn new(x: i32, y : i32) -> Point {
        Point{x,y}
    }
}
impl From<Point> for String {
    fn from(point: Point) -> String {
        format!("({},{})", point.x, point.y)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec![2,1,4,3,6,5]; // We want convert that
    let even = vec.iter().step_by(2);
    let odd = vec.iter().skip(1).step_by(2);
    let points: Vec<Point> 
                = even.zip(odd)
                .map(|(x,y)|Point::new(*x,*y))
                .collect();

    println!("{:?}", points);
}
```

Works like a charm, until we want to add `z` component, and peek into three elements per cycle. I haven't found any appropriate methods from [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html). So, is there already a generic way to iterate over slices of some size over vector and unpack it into my struct(s) or there's no such way and I should implement such iterator myself? Is it a signal to use some heavier machinery like `serde`.

Comment: `itertools` has a [`zip` equivalent](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/macro.izip.html) that supports more than two elements. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @mcarton probably. can't understand example. and overall documentation for izip is poor. and main question can i do it without external crates, only `std`

Comment: “can i do it without external crates, only `std`” is usually the wrong way to think about it. Rust's standard library is small on purpose, and `itertools` is a widely used crate.

Comment: @mcarton not really. If i can do something with tools I already have I don't need extra crate to bloat my binary. So, it is exactly the question - do I need something external or it is doable out-of-the-box. Also, searching for right crate is hard, but now i am aware of `itertools`, thanks to thee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy to do in std for slices using [chunks_exact](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_exact).

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
    z: i32,
}
impl Point {
    fn new(x: i32, y : i32, z: i32) -> Point {
        Point{x,y, z}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec![2,1,4,3,6,5];
    let points: Vec<Point> 
                = vec.chunks_exact(3)
                .map(|chunk|Point::new(chunk[0], chunk[1], chunk[2]))
                .collect();

    println!("{:?}", points);
}
```

Comment: awesome, exactly the thing I've been looking for

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a pre-done method for it, but you can easily write code that can be adjusted pretty quickly to include a third `z` component, similar to this ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4848c770c35eaee2e88c6dbaa9b40c80)):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct PointBuilder {
    x: Option<i32>,
    y: Option<i32>,
    // add a z here
}

impl PointBuilder {
    fn add(&mut self, value: i32) {
        if self.x.is_none() {
            self.x = Some(value);
        } else if self.y.is_none() {
            self.y = Some(value);
        }
        // add a z here
    }

    fn try_build(&self) -> Option<Point> {
        // and one last z in this match expression
        match (self.x, self.y) {
            (Some(x), Some(y)) => Some(Point::new(x, y)),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

fn convert_to_points(data: impl IntoIterator<Item = i32>) -> Vec<Point> {
    data.into_iter()
        .fold((PointBuilder::default(), Vec::<Point>::new()), |(mut builder, mut points), value| {
                builder.add(value);
                if let Some(point) = builder.try_build() {
                    points.push(point);
                    (PointBuilder::default(), points)
                } else {
                    (builder, points)
                }
        })
        .1
}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec![2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]; // We want convert that
    let points = convert_to_points(vec);

    println!("{:?}", points);
}
```

This could of course be done as a proc-macro-derive code generator if you need this for dozens of structs, but I'm not aware of any library that has this implemented already, so it depends on your use case if it'd be worth the effort.

Comment: Builder pattern is ok, but method `add` will grow with every new dimension in struct without providing much valuable code and not error prone . proc macros can save situation, but not really elegant way still. Thanks

Comment: @Sugar you mentioned `serde` in the question, they use proc macros as well. Proc macros themselves don't look elegant but they can enable you to write elegant code

Comment: yes, I am aware of proc macros in `serde`, `miniserde` and some other serialization crates, trying to reduce that kind of routine. Just wanted evade using them without real necessity.